# Are Self-Signed Certificates Acceptable for Signing SAML Tokens?

Tags: web-services, wcf, security, saml-2.0

I'm implementing WS-Trust security on our WCF services using tokens signed by an STS.  Our relying party applications validate that the certificate specified in the token matches the thumbprint specified in the applications' configuration.

Do RPs in WS-Trust require additional validation of the SAML signing certificate beyond its thumbprint?  Would an RP that is outside of my organization require that my token signing certificate is signed by a trusted CA?  Would it also validate if the certificate itself is expired?  Or does the fact that the RP is explicitly specifying the thumbprint it trusts mean that it is only looking for the thumbprint and nothing else?

I realize that certificate validation can be disabled, but I'm mostly concerned about an RP that is outside of my control and possibly following the strictest requirements of WS-Trust and SAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token signing certificates can under be self-signed. During establishment of federation between the IdP and the Relying Party, the token signing cert and issuer string is provided to the Relying Party - so, for signature validation, all that the RP should validate is that the token is issued by an issuer it trusts (issuer value) and is signed by the key that it has for the issuer (thumbprint validation of the key contained in the token isn't enough, RP must validate the digital signature of the token xml document). 
If the identity provider publishes its token signing key on a metadata endpoint - the endpoint must use ssl using a server cert issued by a trusted authority.

Hope that helps.